# jQuery $.session.set() suddenly undefined in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, session

Loaded libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/jquery.session.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js"></script>
```

in Chrome: I had the following experience this morning:

```
$.session.set('auth',response.username);
```

throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

I use:

```
if($.session.get('auth') !== undefined){
    $.getScript('script.js');
}
```

and script.js does not get loaded
this just started happening this morning in Chrome.
Worked in other browsers - even chromium. 
Ran upgrade (Ubuntu Trusty), 
now chromium also not working. 
Works in Chrome on Windows

anyone else have their code break like this overnight?

Update:  If I go incognito in Chrome, this issue disappears and my sites work correctly. Must be something in my settings for my google account?

Anyone have a similar experience ever?

Comment: You're missing a plugin (maybe [this](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)?) which adds `session` to jQuery

Comment: I did not think I had to explicitly say I have the plugin installed, as this just started happening suddenly, and only in chrome. Stackoverflow just forced me to come over to firefox to reply to this comment - could be just my chrome?  But why did chromium stop working after the update?

Comment: I have added the included libraries to the post to clarify.

Comment: I have isolated this to my personal google account settings, but where in the settings, I don't know.  If I go incognito, my site works just fine.  I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reset the settings to factory defaults - did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this..

I have tried, Its work for me..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.session.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // To Read
            $(function () {
                //Set the value to session
                $.session.set("userName", "This is session value");
                //Get the value to session
                alert($.session.get("userName"));
            });

        </script>
    </head>
```

**Here is jQuery.session.js script...**

```
(function ($) {
    $.session = {
        _id: null,
        _cookieCache: undefined,
        _init: function ()
        {
            if (!window.name) {
                window.name = Math.random();
            }
            this._id = window.name;
            this._initCache();
            // See if we've changed protcols
            var matches = (new RegExp(this._generatePrefix() + "=([^;]+);")).exec(document.cookie);
            if (matches && document.location.protocol !== matches[1]) {
                this._clearSession();
                for (var key in this._cookieCache) {
                    try {
                        window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, this._cookieCache[key]);
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                    ;
                }
            }
            document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + "=" + document.location.protocol + ';path=/;expires=' + (new Date((new Date).getTime() + 120000)).toUTCString();
        },
        _generatePrefix: function ()
        {
            return '__session:' + this._id + ':';
        },
        _initCache: function ()
        {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            this._cookieCache = {};
            for (var i in cookies) {
                var kv = cookies[i].split('=');
                if ((new RegExp(this._generatePrefix() + '.+')).test(kv[0]) && kv[1]) {
                    this._cookieCache[kv[0].split(':', 3)[2]] = kv[1];
                }
            }
        },
        _setFallback: function (key, value, onceOnly)
        {
            var cookie = this._generatePrefix() + key + "=" + value + "; path=/";
            if (onceOnly) {
                cookie += "; expires=" + (new Date(Date.now() + 120000)).toUTCString();
            }
            document.cookie = cookie;
            this._cookieCache[key] = value;
            return this;
        },
        _getFallback: function (key)
        {
            if (!this._cookieCache) {
                this._initCache();
            }
            return this._cookieCache[key];
        },
        _clearFallback: function ()
        {
            for (var i in this._cookieCache) {
                document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + i + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            }
            this._cookieCache = {};
        },
        _deleteFallback: function (key)
        {
            document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + key + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            delete this._cookieCache[key];
        },
        get: function (key)
        {
            return window.sessionStorage.getItem(key) || this._getFallback(key);
        },
        set: function (key, value, onceOnly)
        {
            try {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this._setFallback(key, value, onceOnly || false);
            return this;
        },
        'delete': function (key) {
            return this.remove(key);
        },
        remove: function (key)
        {
            try {
                window.sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
            } catch (e) {
            }
            ;
            this._deleteFallback(key);
            return this;
        },
        _clearSession: function ()
        {
            try {
                window.sessionStorage.clear();
            } catch (e) {
                for (var i in window.sessionStorage) {
                    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(i);
                }
            }
        },
        clear: function ()
        {
            this._clearSession();
            this._clearFallback();
            return this;
        }
    };
    $.session._init();
})(jQuery);
```

Please Let me know this code is work for you or not.